# How to use NVL2 function in informix index

Tags: informix

I want to create index using NVL2 function:

```
create index i_name on PERSON (
   NVL2(date1,date2,date3)
);
```

this print error:

```
Routine (nvl2) can not be resolved.
```

What I miss ? Why this doesnt work

Comment: This function was included only at version 11.70. You probably is working with older version. You can easly create your own NVL2() function which simulate the same behave. The limitation will be with the datatype used...

Comment: hm my version is 12.10 ... . Can you show me how should I create new one ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of NVL2 isn't available because builtin functions aren't acceptable for functional indexes. Here is the basic rules to use a functional index at Informix (v12.10) : 
([quoted from the manual](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.perf.doc/ids_prf_398.htm?lang=en))

> Important: The database server imposes the following restrictions on
>   the user-defined routines (UDRs) on which a functional index is
>   defined:
>
> - The arguments cannot be column values of a collection data type.
> - The function cannot return a large object (including built-in types BLOB, BYTE, CLOB, and TEXT).
> - The function cannot be a VARIANT function.
> - The function cannot include any DML statement of SQL.
> - The function must be a UDR, rather than a built-in function. However, you can create an SPL wrapper that calls and returns the
>     value from a built-in function of SQL.

---

Here I'm copying an effective example which you able to run at your environment for test.
Maybe need some little adjustment, because I run this at version 11.70 and set my own dbspaces ....

```
$ cat test.sql
database sysutils;

-- showing my version of informix...
select dbinfo('version','full') from sysmaster:sysdual;

-- creating a database for this test
drop database if exists teste  ;
create database teste in dbadat1dbs with buffered log;

-- registering excompat datablate just to enable the use of the dbms_random function for this example.
execute function sysbldprepare('excompat.1.0', 'create');

-- create my test table
drop table if exists mytables;
create table if not exists mytables ( id int, name char(20), created date, modified date, invalidated date) ;

-- including some records...
insert into mytables(id,name,created) select tabid, tabname , created from sysmaster:systables;

-- creating some random data for this example
update mytables set modified = dbinfo('utc_to_datetime',dbms_random_random()) where name matches '*[xmfz]*';
update mytables set invalidated = dbinfo('utc_to_datetime',dbms_random_random()) where modified is not null;


-- trying use the nvl2... which is not possible because it is a builtin function
create index i1_mytables on mytables ( nvl2(modified, created, invalidated)) ;

-- creating my own function, non variant mode.
drop function if exists my_nvl2_date;
create function if not exists  my_nvl2_date (  dt date , is_null date, not_null date )
  returning date
with (not variant)
return nvl2(dt, is_null, not_null) ;
end function
;

-- create the index
create index i1_mytables on mytables ( my_nvl2_date(modified, created, invalidated)) ;

set explain file to 'test.out' ;
select first 20 * from mytables;
-- here, the index will be used
select first 20 * from mytables where my_nvl2_date(modified, created, invalidated) >= '01/01/2000';
-- this will not use the index because don't match exactly the parameters
select first 20 * from mytables where my_nvl2_date(modified, invalidated, created) >= '01/01/2000';
```

---

Here is the execution. 
Pay attention to explain file , where show when the index is used and isn't.

```
$ dbaccess -e - test.sql
database sysutils;
Database selected.



-- showing my version of informix...
select dbinfo('version','full') from sysmaster:sysdual;

(constant)

IBM Informix Dynamic Server Version 11.70.FC6

1 row(s) retrieved.



-- creating a database for this test
drop database if exists teste  ;
Database dropped.


create database teste in dbadat1dbs with buffered log;
Database closed.


Database created.



-- registering excompat datablate just to enable the use of the dbms_random function for this example.
execute function sysbldprepare('excompat.1.0', 'create');

(expression)

           0

1 row(s) retrieved.



-- create my test table
drop table if exists mytables;
Table dropped.


create table if not exists mytables ( id int, name char(20), created date, modified date, invalidated date) ;
Table created.



-- including some records...
insert into mytables(id,name,created) select tabid, tabname , created from sysmaster:systables;
276 row(s) inserted.



-- creating some random data for this example
update mytables set modified = dbinfo('utc_to_datetime',dbms_random_random()) where name matches '*[xmfz]*';
113 row(s) updated.


update mytables set invalidated = dbinfo('utc_to_datetime',dbms_random_random()) where modified is not null;
113 row(s) updated.




-- trying use the nvl2... which is not possible because it is a builtin function
create index i1_mytables on mytables ( nvl2(modified, created, invalidated)) ;
  674: Routine (nvl2) can not be resolved.
Error in line 26
Near character position 75


-- creating my own function, non variant mode.
drop function if exists my_nvl2_date;
Routine dropped.


create function if not exists  my_nvl2_date (  dt date , is_null date, not_null date )
  returning date
with (not variant)
return nvl2(dt, is_null, not_null) ;;
end function
;
Routine created.

;

-- create the index
create index i1_mytables on mytables ( my_nvl2_date(modified, created, invalidated)) ;
Index created.



set explain file to 'test.out' ;
Explain set.


select first 20 * from mytables;

         id name                 created    modified   invalidated

          1 systables            05/06/2013
          2 syscolumns           05/06/2013 22/10/1942 13/04/2034
          3 sysindices           05/06/2013
          4 systabauth           05/06/2013
          5 syscolauth           05/06/2013
          6 sysviews             05/06/2013
          7 sysusers             05/06/2013
          8 sysdepend            05/06/2013
          9 syssynonyms          05/06/2013 15/03/1981 19/05/1963
         10 syssyntable          05/06/2013
         11 sysconstraints       05/06/2013
         12 sysreferences        05/06/2013 15/08/1912 09/06/1956
         13 syschecks            05/06/2013
         14 sysdefaults          05/06/2013 09/01/1959 01/03/1943
         15 syscoldepend         05/06/2013
         16 sysprocedures        05/06/2013
         17 sysprocbody          05/06/2013
         18 sysprocplan          05/06/2013
         19 sysprocauth          05/06/2013
         20 sysblobs             05/06/2013

20 row(s) retrieved.


-- here, the index will be used
select first 20 * from mytables where my_nvl2_date(modified, created, invalidated) >= '01/01/2000';

         id name                 created    modified   invalidated

          2 syscolumns           05/06/2013 22/10/1942 13/04/2034
          9 syssynonyms          05/06/2013 15/03/1981 19/05/1963
         12 sysreferences        05/06/2013 15/08/1912 09/06/1956
         14 sysdefaults          05/06/2013 09/01/1959 01/03/1943
         25 sysfragments         05/06/2013 29/10/1951 11/02/1953
         28 sysfragauth          05/06/2013 06/12/2024 03/11/1948
         30 sysxtdtypes          05/06/2013 20/03/1909 03/05/1975
         32 sysxtddesc           05/06/2013 23/04/1933 23/07/1961
         35 syslogmap            05/06/2013 01/03/2015 30/05/2020
         37 sysxtdtypeauth       05/06/2013 16/03/1911 26/12/2037
         40 sysams               05/06/2013 02/06/1940 19/08/2000
         41 systabamdata         05/06/2013 21/04/2032 17/02/1907
         45 systracemsgs         05/06/2013 14/04/2006 09/11/1936
         49 sysxasourcetypes     05/06/2013 03/04/1994 28/05/1972
         50 sysxadatasources     05/06/2013 09/09/1967 29/11/1978
         51 sysseclabelcomponent 05/06/2013 26/04/1979 21/09/1984
         52 sysseclabelcomponent 05/06/2013 10/10/2035 16/06/2021
         54 syssecpolicycomponen 05/06/2013 23/08/1962 20/05/1983
         55 syssecpolicyexemptio 05/06/2013 09/01/1966 04/12/2027
         57 sysseclabelnames     05/06/2013 09/03/1948 03/09/1937

20 row(s) retrieved.


-- this will not use the index because don't match exactly the parameters
select first 20 * from mytables where my_nvl2_date(modified, invalidated, created) >= '01/01/2000';

         id name                 created    modified   invalidated

          1 systables            05/06/2013
          2 syscolumns           05/06/2013 22/10/1942 13/04/2034
          3 sysindices           05/06/2013
          4 systabauth           05/06/2013
          5 syscolauth           05/06/2013
          6 sysviews             05/06/2013
          7 sysusers             05/06/2013
          8 sysdepend            05/06/2013
         10 syssyntable          05/06/2013
         11 sysconstraints       05/06/2013
         13 syschecks            05/06/2013
         15 syscoldepend         05/06/2013
         16 sysprocedures        05/06/2013
         17 sysprocbody          05/06/2013
         18 sysprocplan          05/06/2013
         19 sysprocauth          05/06/2013
         20 sysblobs             05/06/2013
         21 sysopclstr           05/06/2013
         22 systriggers          05/06/2013
         23 systrigbody          05/06/2013

20 row(s) retrieved.
Database closed.
```

---

Here is the explain file with the 3 selects executed.
Observe only the second select used the index.

```
$ cat test.out

QUERY: (OPTIMIZATION TIMESTAMP: 03-21-2014 21:43:22)
------
select first 20 * from mytables

Estimated Cost: 0
Estimated # of Rows Returned: 276

  1) informix.mytables: SEQUENTIAL SCAN


Query statistics:
-----------------

The final cost of the plan is reduced because of the FIRST n specification in
 the query.

  Table map :
  ----------------------------
  Internal name     Table name
  ----------------------------
  t1                mytables

  type     table  rows_prod  est_rows  rows_scan  time       est_cost
  -------------------------------------------------------------------
  scan     t1     20         276       38         00:00.00   1


QUERY: (OPTIMIZATION TIMESTAMP: 03-21-2014 21:43:22)
------
select first 20 * from mytables where my_nvl2_date(modified, created, invalidated) >= '01/01/2000'

Estimated Cost: 1
Estimated # of Rows Returned: 92

  1) informix.mytables: INDEX PATH

    (1) Index Name: informix.i1_mytables
        Index Keys: informix.my_nvl2_date(modified,created,invalidated)   (Serial, fragments: ALL)
        Lower Index Filter: informix.my_nvl2_date(informix.mytables.modified ,informix.mytables.created ,informix.mytables.invalidated )>= 01/01/2000

UDRs in query:
--------------
    UDR id  :   540
    UDR name:   my_nvl2_date
    UDR id  :   540
    UDR name:   my_nvl2_date

Query statistics:
-----------------

The final cost of the plan is reduced because of the FIRST n specification in
 the query.

  Table map :
  ----------------------------
  Internal name     Table name
  ----------------------------
  t1                mytables

  type     table  rows_prod  est_rows  rows_scan  time       est_cost
  -------------------------------------------------------------------
  scan     t1     20         92        20         00:00.00   1


QUERY: (OPTIMIZATION TIMESTAMP: 03-21-2014 21:43:22)
------
select first 20 * from mytables where my_nvl2_date(modified, invalidated, created) >= '01/01/2000'

Estimated Cost: 2
Estimated # of Rows Returned: 92

  1) informix.mytables: SEQUENTIAL SCAN

        Filters: informix.my_nvl2_date(informix.mytables.modified ,informix.mytables.invalidated ,informix.mytables.created )>= 01/01/2000

UDRs in query:
--------------
    UDR id  :   540
    UDR name:   my_nvl2_date

Query statistics:
-----------------

The final cost of the plan is reduced because of the FIRST n specification in
 the query.

  Table map :
  ----------------------------
  Internal name     Table name
  ----------------------------
  t1                mytables

  type     table  rows_prod  est_rows  rows_scan  time       est_cost
  -------------------------------------------------------------------
  scan     t1     20         92        38         00:00.00   3
```